# How to identify the precision of long double datatype

Tags: c, long-double

My compiler is telling me that the size of `sizeof(long double)` is 16 byte, which means it can represent a number up `2^128`. Now, I want to know until how many digits the precision can handle. For instance, if `x= 0.1234567812345678`, can `long double` identify the exact precision of `x` here?

Thank you

Comment: "[...] which means it can represent a number up 2^128" -- uh no, it's not an integer you know. All bits are not available for storing the integer part.

Comment: Note that the actual floating-point number is probably only 80 bits (if you are on x86).  The compiler reserves 128 bits for alignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to know until how many digits the precision can handle.

`LDBL_DIG`, in `<float.h>`, is the number of minimum number of significant decimal digits that will be converted from text to `long double` *distinctively*.  It is at least 10 and may be 18 or so on your platform.  `0.1234567812345678` and `123.4567812345678` have 16 significant decimal digits.

---

> My compiler is telling me that the size of sizeof(long double) is 16 byte, which means it can represent a number up 2^128

It could mean something like that if `long double` was an integer, yet floating point numbers are distributed [logarithmically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43284459/2410359).  Further, some systems do not use all 16 bytes for data.  Some are padding. [@unwind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43545753/how-to-identify-the-precision-of-long-double-datatype/43547163#comment74143728_43545753) [@Sven Marnach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43545753/how-to-identify-the-precision-of-long-double-datatype/43547163#comment74145280_43545753).  Use the values in `<float.h>` to characterize the `long double` your platform is using.

---

> if `x= 0.1234567812345678`, can `long double` identify the exact precision of `x`?

No, unless you are on a rare platform that uses decimal floating point.

Most platforms use a binary floating point.  So unless the number can be represented as an exact sum of powers of 2, like 42.125, the value saved as a `long double` will be a nearby approximation.   Code will convert text `0.1234567812345678` to the *nearest* `long double` which may have an exact value  of `0.1234567812345677972896140772718354128301143646240234375`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Clear and precise answers :)

Answer (score 5):

The [header `float.h`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cfloat) contains some macros desribing the precision of the different floating-point data types; e.g. `LDBL_MANT_DIG` gives you the number of binary digits in the mantissa of a `long double`.

If you don't understand the format of floating-point numbers, I recommend you read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: Nice succinct answer: Detail `LDBL_MANT_DIG` in number of radix digits, which are _usually_ binary ones.