# Is there a function to retrieve the number of available distinct values within a range?

Tags: c++, floating-point, range, normalization

I'm using double precision floating point variables within an application I'm making.

I normalize some ranges of values. Going from (for example; I've many ranges) `-48.0` to `48.0` to `0.0` to `1.0`, using this simply function:

```
double ToNormalizedParam(double nonNormalizedValue, double min, double max, double shape) {
    return pow((nonNormalizedValue - min) / (max - min), 1.0 / shape);
}
```

I'd like to know the differences in available and distinct values mapping from a range to another.

Is there a ready-to-go function in C++? I've looked at `numeric_limits`, but I can't find anything useful.

Comment: You should be aware that, in c++, a range is usually taken to mean a pair of iterators that denote the beginning and end of a set of elements in a container. While the question isn't technically wrong, the terminology may lead to some confusion.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: I'm not talking about containers

Comment: Off the top of my head, no. Rolling your own doesn't sound fun either, but is plausible I suppose

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. You have a range of values and you want to count distinct values? Is that correct?

Comment: @Ron question is about a range of floating point values, in the sense of an interval [a,b], not a range of elements in a container or iterators

Comment: @Ron check it out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place

Comment: @Ron no, if you think there is infinite number of floating points in [a,b] you need to either review floating points or infinity ;)

Comment: @Ron i am not familiar with Computer Science SE, but as the question is asking for a concrete solution in c++, i dont see why it would not fit here

Comment: If you are interested in preserving as much available and distinct values as possible, you may consider to use `long double`s for the intermediate calculations. As it's now, you are already restricting to [0,1] and then applying the `pow` function, loosing some other distinct values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a ready-to-go function in C++?

Perhaps.  If not, it is easy enough to form a function to assigned a sequence number to each `double` value.

Assuming matching FP/integer  for endian & size and typical FP layout like [double64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), the below is valid `-INF` to `INF`.

```
// Return a sequence number for each `double` value.
// Numerically sequential `double` values will have successive (+1) sequence numbers.
uint64_t double_sequence(double x) {
  uint64_t u64;
  memcpy(&u64, &x, sizeof u64);
  if (u64 & 0x8000000000000000) {
    u64 ^= 0x8000000000000000;
    return 0x8000000000000000 - u64;
  }
  return u64 + 0x8000000000000000;
}
```

> Is there a function to retrieve the number of available distinct values within a range?

Simply subtract the sequence numbers.  +1 or -1 depending on if an [open or closed range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Terminology).

```
double_sequence(1.0)  - double_sequence(0.0)   + 1 --> 0x3ff0000000000001
double_sequence(48.0) - double_sequence(-48.0) + 1 --> 0x8090000000000001
```

---

Notes:
Keep in mind that FP are logarithmically distributed overall and linear within  powers of 2.
For about half of all FP, `|x| < 1.0`.
There are as many FP numbers 0.5 to 1.0 as between 16.0 to 32.0.
There are over twice as many `double` in the `[-48.0 ... 48.0]` versus `[0.0 ... 1.0]` range, primarily due to negative values.

Comment: I don't get `There are as many FP numbers 0.5 to 1.0 as between 16.0 to 32.0.`. If between `0.5` and `1.0` there are (let say) `X` possible values, between `0.0` and `40.0` there are those `X` plus the ones between `0.0-0.5` and `1.0-40.0`. Way big. How can they be "the same" considering different ranges? :O

Comment: @markzzz Does [distributed linearly but logarithmically in linear groups](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43284459/2410359) help?

Comment: @markzzz X values between 1.0 to 2.0, X values between 2.0 to 4.0, X values between 4.0 to 8.0, etc.  X values between 0.25 to 0.125, X values between 0.125 to 0.0625, X values between 0.0625 to 0.03125, etc

Comment: no you misunderstand me :) http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5731f7dd8f486e68 : the more the range is "huge", the more available values you can use. 10 and 91 setting 1 magnitude up. X change for every range.

Comment: @markzzz Between 0.5 to 1.0, your program will report X different values, maybe about 4.5e15 (if you let it run long enough).  Between 16.0 to 32.0, it will report the same.  Try with `float`, X should be about 8,300,000.

Comment: @markzzz Your code compares 2 ranges, the seconds is a [superset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset#Definitions) of the first, so a larger number is expected.  My "as many FP numbers 0.5 to 1.0 as between 16.0 to 32.0" compares 2 separate [disjoint sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_sets).  Yes, [0 40.0] has more members than sets [0.5 1.0] and  [16.0 32.0] combined.  Yet that is not the point.  Set [0.5 1.0] and set [16.0 32.0] each have the same member count.

Comment: Man, Am I on drugs? I'm talking about how many different values there (i.e. I can use) between two different sets. You also said this: "Yes, [0 40.0] has more **members** than sets [0.5 1.0] and [16.0 32.0] combined."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158607/discussion-between-markzzz-and-chux).

Answer (score 1):

Given a positive IEEE 754 double precision floating point number with exponent `e` and mantissa `m`, both interpreted as an integer, the distinct values (not counting denormalized values) less than it but greater than zero will be exactly `m + (e - 1) * 2^52`.

Which could be extracted like so

```
#include<iostream>
#include<tuple>
#include<cstdint>
#include<cstring>

using std::uint64_t;

std::tuple<uint64_t, uint64_t, uint64_t> explode(double d)
{
    static_assert(sizeof(double) == 8);
    uint64_t u;
    std::memcpy(&u, &d, sizeof(d));
    return { (u & 0x8000000000000000) >> 63,
             (u & 0x7FF0000000000000) >> 52,
              u & 0x000FFFFFFFFFFFFF };
}

uint64_t distinct(double d)
{
    auto [_, e, m] = explode(d);
    return m + ((e - 1) << 52);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "[-48, 48]: " << 2 * distinct(48) << "\n[0, 1]: " << distinct(1) << '\n';
}
```

[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/389da19ee4f87f63)

Comment: I'm not sure this is what the OP's *really* looking for, because the map given by ToNormalizedParam ( and its formal inverse ) is neither injective nor surjective and depends on rounding mode ( and iee754 conformance )...

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes I made the only conclusion I can, we'll have to wait for OP to clarify I suppose.

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes how ToNormalizedParam round doesn't matter here. Different values will collide on different ones, yes, but the range between 0 and 1, despite the round function, is always that on a fixed machine

Comment: i.e. I'm not asking which numbers will be used after the normalization, but how many possible values I can use